# AdBlock blocking CSS and Images on .NET 4.5 web site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, adblock

I created a new web site using the default web-forms web site template that comes with Visual Studio 2012.  Just went to File--> New Website --> C# --> Asp.Net Web Site, and let it create it's basic template.

Then I hit F5 to debug and it runs fine and I get that default welcome page with the aqua green block, etc...  but when I add it to IIS and browse to it using localhost/WebsiteName in Chrome, the AdBlock plugin blocks all of the CSS and Images so all I see is black-and white un-styled text.  When I disable AdBlock, the styling and images return and it looks normal just like it did when debugging.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the Bundle Referencing, but I'm not sure what's going on.

What specifically is AdBlock blocking?

Why isn't it blocking it when debugging through Visual Studio, only when browsed to it via localhost/WebsiteName?

What can I do to prevent users with AdBlock from having this content blocked when it is clearly not advertising?

Comment: Can you assign a Domain name to it via your hosts file? c:\windows\system 32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must assume you have a matching rule in your Adblock config. If you Go to **Adblock - Options** and turn on **"I'm an advanced user, show me advanced options."** you should then be able to reload your page and go to **"Show the resource list"** from the Adblock button. All items on the page will be displayed, the blocked items will be in red and the matching filter shown.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip. It turns out that AdBlock blocks anything matching /advertising/* and the actual name of my app is "Advertising" because it will be an advertiser management system for my organization. Looks like I need to find a new name for that folder.  When debugging is only went to localhost:5538/ but localhost/advertising/default.aspx got blocked because of the word "advertising" in the path.